# ReactError #130 | Element must be string not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm new on this platform and a have a problem by a reactjs output.

If try to create a table with react-table but if got the following error:
This error says, that the react expected a string, but I give them an object. But I don't understand which object is meant.

Have you an idea, why I got this error and how I fixed this error?

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Error: Minified React error #130; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at l (react-dom.production.min.js:12)
    at qc (react-dom.production.min.js:43)
    at K (react-dom.production.min.js:53)
    at n (react-dom.production.min.js:57)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:62
    at f (react-dom.production.min.js:130)
    at beginWork (react-dom.production.min.js:135)
    at d (react-dom.production.min.js:158)
    at f (react-dom.production.min.js:159)
    at g (react-dom.production.min.js:159)
```

**Code:**

```
class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        text: this.props.test
    }

    render() {

        const data = this.state.text;
        console.log(data);

        const tmpData = [{
            "test": data.test,
            "test1": data.test1,
            "test2": data.test2
            }];

        const itemData = JSON.stringify(tmpData);
        console.log(itemData);

        return (
                  <div>
                    <br />
                    <strong>Note: Having the console open will slow performance</strong>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <ReactTable
                      data={itemData}
                      columns={[
                      {
                          Header: "Test",
                          accessor: "test"
                      },
                      {
                          Header: "Test1",
                          accessor: "test1"
                      }, 
                      {
                          Header: "Test2",
                          accessor: "test2",
                      }
                      ]}
                    />
                    <br />
                  </div>
                )
    }
}
```

Thank you!
Regards,
MCW

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is not needed. Just pass `tmpData` as is to `data`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i got the same error.

Comment: I know you have that same error, because nothing wrong with the code you posted other than incorrect usage of data. But it would lead to different error anyway. So no, posted code is not relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a module import problem. When React tries to mount ReactTable component, the type of the component is an object, because ReactTable variable contains not the ReactTable component, but ReactTable module.

The right import form global module should be:

```
const ReactTable = window.ReactTable.default;
```

You can try it out here:
https://codepen.io/mazhuravlev/pen/QQdXbB. To reproduce the problem, remove .default from ReactTable import statement.

```
const ReactTable = window.ReactTable.default;

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const tmpData = [{
            "test": 'test',
            "test1": 'test1',
            "test2": 'test2'
        }];
       const r = <ReactTable
                data={tmpData}
                columns={[
                    {
                        Header: "Test",
                        accessor: "test"
                    },
                    {
                        Header: "Test1",
                        accessor: "test1"
                    },
                    {
                        Header: "Test2",
                        accessor: "test2",
                    }
                ]}
            />;
        debugger;
        return r;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: If i change them, than a got the following error:
'Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:23
    at run (babel.js:61531)
    at check (babel.js:61597)
    at babel.js:61624
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (babel.js:61549)'

Comment: Which webjar i must include to use the export?

Comment: It depends on you module and build setup, export default is for ES6 modules. Which one are you using? Can you make a github repo of this project?

Comment: We must use ES5, because we support websites with old browser version.

Comment: Is it possible, that ES5 doesn't support ReactTable?

Comment: Added a codepen. Your error is likely to be import related. Run the codepen with devtools open and notice that r value, especially r.type. Then delete .default part from import and you will have that import error. Notice r.type again.

Comment: Try "const ReactTable = window.ReactTable;" in codepen, it will fail.

Comment: Now its works the problem was, the `const ReactTable = window.ReactTable.default;`. After i implement this code line, now i get the table.